# C++ - How am I able to call a copy constructor for std::thread?

Tags: c++, c++17

So according to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread: the copy constructor for `std::thread` is deleted and is the reason I cannot do (results in a compilation error):

```cpp
std::thread t1;
std::thread t2 = t1;
```

However I am somehow able to do:

```cpp
std::thread t1;
t1 = std::thread();
```

I was under the impression that the above code creates a temporary `std::thread` object and copies it into `t1` but the copy constructor doesn't exist (as is shown in the top snippet which doesn't compile).

So what exactly is going on in the second snippet?

Comment: Are you familiar with move semantics? If not, see [What is move semantics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/what-is-move-semantics)

Comment: Since the left side of the equal sign in `t1 = std::thread();` is an existing variable, not a declaration, you should be thinking [assignment](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/operator%3D) rather than [construction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread). *(In one sense it does not matter since copy-assignment is also deleted. Hence this is a comment, not an answer.)*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second one uses move assignment. `std::thread` can be moved, but not copied.

This should also work:  `std::thread t2 = std::move(t1);`  , which will leave `t2` managing whatever thread `t1` was managing , and `t1` will be empty.

Comment: If std::thread *did* have a copy constructor would it then be copied instead? I.e is the behavior to try and copy and use move instead if there is no copy constructor? or does doing this always call move?

Comment: @user3690467: No; move is an optimized copy. Move is used if it wouldn't cause a problem, such as in the cases of prvalues or direct request (ie: `std::move`).

Comment: In case it's needed, here's some reading to understand some of the above terminology: [What are rvalues, lvalues, xvalues, glvalues, and prvalues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/what-are-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-and-prvalues)

Comment: Assignment or construction from rvalues tries the move first, only falling back to copy if the move constructor/assignment-op didn't exist.  (note that "normal" classes default to having compiler-generated move operations, so there would be no fallback in those cases -- full discussion of this is beyond scope of comments :)